# is there any solution for id adp-summary and adp-text overlapping issue in directionsDisplay in map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, cordova

The problem is source address getting overlapping with time detail in dialog i.e i will open map in my application in getDirection button is there when i click on that it will open the dialog with select option, there i will select one company it will display the direction details from source address to destination address with full details (like turn left go straight take right) but i am getting the overlapping issue on source address with time details

I tried the below code, to fix the issue

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          const container = document.getElementById("distance_info");              
          const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
               adjustSummaryPosition();
          });
          const config = { attributes: true, characterData: true };                
          observer.observe(container, config);
            
          directionsDisplay.setPanel(container);
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
            
          $("#results").show();
    } else {
          $("#results").hide();
   }
});

function adjustSummaryPosition() {
    const adpText = document.querySelector('.adp-text');
    const adpSummary = document.querySelector('.adp-summary');
    const adpLegal = document.querySelector('.adp-legal');
    if (adpText && adpSummary) {
        const adpTextHeight = adpText.offsetHeight ;
        const adpTextMarginTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(adpText).marginTop);
        adpSummary.style.marginTop = adpTextHeight - 20 +  'px';
        adpLegal.style.marginTop = adpTextHeight - 45 + 'px';
    } else {
        console.log("adpText or adpSummary element not found.");
    }
}
```

i tried by using the css to fix the overlapping issue but still its not fixed because the source address will vary according to the latitude and longitude